# Backbone router with multiple parameters

Tags: javascript, url, backbone.js, router, hashtag

I need to get this to work:

```
routes: {
  ':product' : 'showProduct',
  ':product/:detail': 'showProductDetail'
```

showProductDetail never gets called while the ':product' route is set even if it is set afterwards. I tried the following

```
routes: {
  ':product(/:detail)': showProductOrDetail
}
```

But this will not get called when only the second parameter changes.
It is important that I have the product itself or the **product and detail in the url**.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There's a little hacky solution to your problem. I have a feeling there is a nicer way to do this but that should work:

```
routes: {
    "product/:id": "showProduct",
    "product/:id/details/:did": "showDetails"
},

showProduct: function(id) {
    this.showDetails(id);
},

showDetails: function(id, did) {
    // Check did for undefined

}
```

Comment: In this case your approach would work but as I said I want to have the product in the second route as well so I can do something like: mywebsite.com/#category/1/product/3/detail/1

Comment: This doesn't work if I only call mywebsite/com/#product/1 right?

Comment: it doesn't hurt me if i thank you @SzymonDrosdzol with a +1 ;)

Answer (score 3):

A late response (over a year).. but you can use RegEx in a backbone router to achieve this. 
My example presumes the parameters are going to start with a number.

ie: localhost:8888/#root/1param/2param

```
var router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    initialize: function () {
        // Use REGEX to get multiple parameters
        this.route(/root/, 'page0'); 
        this.route(/root\/(\d+\S+)/, 'page1'); 
        this.route(/root\/(\d+\S+)\/(\d+\S+)/, 'page2');
    },
    page0:function(){
        console.log("no id");
    },
    page1:function(id1){
        console.log(id1);
    },
    page2:function(id1,id2){
        console.log(id1);
        console.log(id2);
    }
});
```

Hope this helps.